# hashの記法について(キーに対するバリューを取得する際、 hoge[:title] と hoge.title という二種類のやり方があり)

Tags: ruby

jsonからの値を取り扱う際に、いつも以下の2通りのパターンのどちらなのかわからず混乱してしまいます。

hoge[:title]
hoge.title

※キーに対するバリューを取得する際を想定

Jsonをパースした際のハッシュの取り扱い

```
hoge = resp.body.map{|hoge| JSON.parse(hoge)}

OK
hoge[0].title

NG
hoge[0]["title"]
```

一方、ハッシュを変数に入れる際？は

```
hoge = {:id=>"123", :title=>"テスト"}

OK
hoge["title"]

NG
hoge.title
```

変数に入れるか入れないかで挙動が違うのかなと思ったのですが、
ピンポイントで解説している文献に出会わなかったため、質問させて頂きました。

また、hashでのfindの挙動も時々不思議に思うことがあります。
こちらももし参考になるURlなどございましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: いまいち状況がよくわかってないのですが、上コードでの`hoge[0].class`と下コードでの`hoge.class`をそれぞれ見てみると何が違うのかわかるのでは？

Comment: どのようなJSONデータを処理しているのか示してもらえれば、回答してもらいやすいと思います。

Comment: 実際に動かしているコードを極力そのまま載せてほしいです。また、もっと前後の処理のコードも一緒に載せてください。ご質問のコードだと情報が不足しています。

Answer (score 1):

```
hoge = resp.body.map{|hoge| JSON.parse(hoge)}
```

が何に由来しているのかも中身が何かわからないので実際に起きていることはわかりませんが、素の`Hash`には

```
hash.title
```

のように、メソッド形式でキーを指定して値を指定するような機能はありません。出来るとしたらそれは`Hash`を拡張したものかまたは全く別のオブジェクトです。

Answer (score 0):

あてずっぽうですが `JSON::Parser.new` の引数に独自のクラスを指定してるのではないでしょうか。

> new(source, options => {}) -> JSON::Parser[permalink][rdoc]
>
> :object_class
>       JSON のオブジェクトを変換するクラスを指定します。デフォルトは Hash です。
>
> :array_class
>      JSON の配列を変換するクラスを指定します。デフォルトは Array です。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/JSON=3a=3aParser/s/new.html